# Automatically or mass create bookmarks for a glossary?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a document with a large glossary in Word 2010 which I would like to link to when those terms are referenced in the document.  However, it's time consuming and repetitive to create a bookmark for each glossary term.  Is there a way to create the bookmarks automatically or en masse?

Comment: @CharlieRB Doing it manually, and searching Google.

Comment: How are you linking them? Does every instance of each word throughout the document need to be linked? Are you comfortable with VBA?

Comment: @CharlieRB I can link them manually, I don't mind that, and yes I know VBA, but mainly for Access and Excel.

Comment: See Also: [Generate bookmarks in Word 2010 programmatically, with the header name as the bookmark name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333817/generate-bookmarks-in-word-2010-programmatically-with-the-header-name-as-the-bo)

Comment: You don't want to generate bookmarks for every word, rather bookmark each word in the glossary, then using VBA to create a link to the that bookmark at each instance of the word throughout the document. I will post an answer if I can get it to do what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why I didn't think of this before. This is a simple solution using `Find & Replace` which I think will work for you.

1. Highlight the word in the glossary.
2. Create a bookmark for that word.
3. With the bookmarked word highlighted, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.
4. Open the Find & Replace window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>)
5. For the `Find what:` if it's not already populated, add the word.
6. For the `Replace with:` type `^c`.
7. Click <kbd>Find Next</kbd> so it will find the first instance of the word. If it asks to start at the beginning of the document select <kbd>Yes</kbd>.
8. For each instance of the word, choose to replace it. (If you choose to use <kbd>Replace All</kbd>, keep in mind it will create a link if it find the word as part of another word.)
9. Repeat this process for each word in the glossary.

Comment: It's creating the link I'd like to automate ...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood because I don't see know how any macro or VBA would know what word to create a bookmark with. So, I thought you meant automate linking to them.